# Remove element with specific id.. where my id comes from an angular expression

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am adding elements dynamically using an Angular directive as :

```
.directive('myNote',  function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            delete: '&',
            note:'='
        },
        controller: function()
        {
            this.delete = function(){

            $('my-note').remove();
        };
        },
        controllerAs: 'noteCtrl',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var $el = $(element);
            $el.draggable();
        },
        template: '<div class="note yellow" id={{note.id}}>' +                 
                  '<img ng-src="close.png" align="right" ng-click="noteCtrl.delete()">' +
                  '<br>'+
                  '<blockquote>'+
                  '<cite class="title">{{note.title}}</cite> <br><br> {{note.content}}' +
                  '</blockquote>' +             
                  '</div>'
    };
})
```

this way, the divs get added as div id=1, div id=2 and so on every time I add a my-note. I want to delete a specific note when i click on the img tag of the div. How can I achieve this?

P.S: $('my-note').remove(); removes all the notes. I only want to remove the note i clicked on.

Here is the HTML as requested:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="note in notes">
  <my-note note="note" delete="deleteNote(note)"></my-note>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an inline `onclick=` handler. Do it "the jQuery way" using a delegated event handler (attached to a non-changing ancestor element):

First, add a class to the image button (and remove the `onclick` handler):

```
 '<div class="note yellow" id={{note.id}}>' +                 
              '<img ng-src="close.png" align="right" class="deleteme">' +
              '<br>'+
              '<blockquote>'+
              '<cite class="title">{{note.title}}</cite> <br><br> {{note.content}}' +
              '</blockquote>' +             
              '</div>'
```

Then add a delegated event handler to a common ancestor:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteme', function(){
   $(this).closest('.note').remove();
});
```

The `this` of the handler will be the image/button, so you then just find the item you want to remove using `closest()`. In your case that is the element with `class="note"`.

### Notes:

- Delegated event handlers work by listening for the event (click) to bubble up to a common ancestor. `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient. They then apply the jQuery selector, at event time, to the elements in the bubble-chain. It then applies your function, to only the matching elements that caused the event. The `this` value passed to the event function will be the matched item that was clicked.
- inline handlers (like `onclick=""`) separate your event registration from the event handler for no benefit.
- You should try chose the closest common ancestor, to the elements, as the target of the delegated event. Even though `document` is one level higher, it is a better default than `body` as `body` can fail in certain circumstances.
- Delegated events are faster to connect than individual event handlers. The trade-off is a slight reduction in speed at event time, but (and it's a big but), the speed difference at event time will never be noticed because you cannot click a mouse 50,0000 times per second :)

### Update (based on HTML added):

As you have a parent `UL` for the notes, change your HTML to have an ID on the `UL` and target that:

e.g.

```
<ul id="mynotes">
 <li ng-repeat="note in notes">
  <my-note note="note" delete="deleteNote(note)"></my-note>
 </li>
</ul>
```

then the code becomes

```
$('#mynotes').on('click', '.deleteme', function(){
   $(this).closest('.note').remove();
});
```

Comment: @dsg: No problem. Accept as answer when you can. I will add some more notes for posterity :)

Comment: i was stuck on how to get to the closest ancestor. your notes helped me. thanks again :)

Comment: I would need to see your HTML, as there is probably a closer element you can use. A parent div or table perhaps? So long as it is a common ancestor to all the `.note` elements.

Comment: i added it to the question. though i do not think there is a closer ancestor element possible. is it?

Comment: If you add an id to the `UL`, you can target that. The speed difference is nothing you would ever notice, so `document` is fine almost all of the time. :)

Comment: adding it to the ul will be better practice i guess. will do :)

Comment: Added that to the answer for you. Enjoy :)

Comment: @JohnHascall: It;s a delegated handler. The selector in the second parameter determines the `this`. i.e. it is the clicked `.deleteme` element :)